# Azure DevOps: PR Checks not triggering when using Github Webhooks

Tags: github, azure-devops

I'm trying to get automated PR checks running for my pipelines, but somehow the trigger is not working for pull requests.

I'm using YAML files and the change/trigger configuration looks something like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - libs/lib-a/*
      - package.json
      - package-lock.json

pr:
  drafts: false
  paths:
    include:
      - libs/lib-a/*
      - package.json
      - package-lock.json
```

My connection to Github is working, as changes to `master` do automatically run the pipeline. Nevertheless, opening a PR (and pushing changes to the PR branch) does not trigger any automated PR runs.

The webhooks are fired to DevOps though:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<ORG>/_apis/public/hooks/externalEvents?publisherId=github&channelId=<ID>&api-version=7.1-preview
```

What could be the reason here?

I've recreated the service connection multiple times, even the pipeline itself.
The PR also includes at least one change in the related directory / file.

**What other configuration mistakes could be related to this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

PR trigger causes a pipeline to run whenever a pull request is opened with one of the specified target branches, or when updates are made to such a pull request. It doesn't monitor on webhook, we have separated [webhook trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#define-a-webhooks-resource).

> My connection to Github is working, as changes to master do automatically run the pipeline. Nevertheless, opening a PR (and pushing changes to the PR branch) does not trigger any automated PR runs.

Please follow below items for a check:

1. Go to project setting, check if you toggled off the setting:

[image]

2. Edit yaml -> Clcik triggers on the top right virtical 3 dots -> check if you override the pull request trigger.

[image]

Comment: Hi @tpschmidt, may i know if it works? let me know if there's any update or queries, thanks.

Comment: Hi, this didn't help at all. I was already in contact with Microsoft support via official support request and we also couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @tpschmidt, PR trigger is monitoring on the PR change, not webhook. If it doesn't work, and you have `confirmed` above setting, suggest to go to github repo setting, integration, check github apps, uninstall `Azure Pipelines` app. Then go to devops, create the connection again, it will install the app again on github. Please also share the solution if it's resolved by support request, thanks,